# TypeScript : Value assigned inside HTTPClient scope is not accessible from outside (within the same function)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

On Load, I'm calling the function `getData()` which will read & map the response to `Data[]` model and returns back the result. But the function returning `undefined` object though it's value is assigned.

```
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Data} from "../model";

export class Service {  
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

   getData():Data[]{
    var data: Data[];
    this.http.get(url,{ responseType: 'blob'}).subscribe(response => {
      response.text().then(value => {
          data = <Data[]>JSON.parse(value);
          console.log(data);  ----> {Printing the values as expected i.e., Data Array}
       });
    });
    console.log(data);  ----> {Printing Undefined}
    return testData;
   }

   onLoad(){
      var data:Data[] = this.getData();
      console.log(data)  ---------> {Printing Undefined}
   }
}
```

**Data** Class :

```
export class Data{
 id:number;
 name:string;
 value:string;
}
```

Comment: Value is defined asynchronously. Any statements that directly depend on the async data should be async as well (should be inside the subscription). More details on async data here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/6513921

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just show what I would like to do, here's a little bit reconstruction for your codes:

```
import {from, Observable} from 'rxjs';  // <= several imports you might care
import {map, switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators';  // <= several imports you might care

export class Service {  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getData(): Observable<Data[]> {
    return this.http.get(someurl, {responseType: 'blob'})
      .pipe(
        switchMap((blob: Blob) => {
          return from(blob.text());
        }),
        map(text => {
          return JSON.parse(text) as Data[];
        })
      );
  }

  onLoad(): void {
    this.getData().subscribe((data: Data[]) => {
      console.log(data); // <=== this is where you can log data
    });
  }
}
```

> The basic idea is you should return a aync(aka Observable) result for your http request, and pipe the first result(type of Blob) to another Observable(which is built from a promise) of string value, then map it to a Data array at last, in onLoad you should subscribe the async result and check the data in subscription. In a word, you should keep the data flow asynchronously until it is been resolved

Comment: The getData() can be used straight away on your component with the [async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe)

Answer (score 2):

Http calls are async calls. Subsequent call will get executed and will not wait for the promise to be resolve.

Your dependent code should be written once it resolved.